# Android canny, hough transform. I want to go back to original image

Tags: java, android, opencv, hough-transform, canny-operator

Android, I used canny and hough transform to make line detection on phone screen. However, I can't find a way to get back to original image(I mean HSV to BGR). I want to see keep lines well with BGR image. Thank you!

My code, please let me know which code I have to put in.

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2{
    private static final String TAG="MainActivity";

    private Mat mRgba;
    private Mat mGray;


    Scalar scalarLow,scalarHigh;///
    Mat mat1,mat2;////
    Rect rect;////
    Rect roi_rect;///
    private Mat m_matRoi;////
    Point rect1, rect2;///////
```

```
    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width ,int height){
        mRgba=new Mat(height,width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
        mGray =new Mat(height,width,CvType.CV_8UC1);

        mat1 = new Mat(height,width,CvType.CV_8UC4);
        mat2 = new Mat(height,width,CvType.CV_8UC4);

    }
    public void onCameraViewStopped(){
        mRgba.release();
    }
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame){
        mRgba=inputFrame.rgba();/////mRgba = image, matInput 과 같은 역할
        mGray=inputFrame.gray();


        double m_dWscale = (double)  1/3;
        double m_dHscale = (double) 1/4;
        int mRoiWidth = (int)(mRgba.size().width * m_dWscale);
        int mRoiHeight = (int)(mRgba.size().height * m_dHscale);

        int mRoiX = (int) (mRgba.size().width - mRoiWidth) ;
        int mRoiY = (int) (mRgba.size().height - mRoiHeight) ;

        //rect = new Rect(mRoiX,mRoiY,mRoiWidth,mRoiHeight);
        rect1 =new Point(mRoiX, mRoiY);
        rect2 = new Point(mRoiWidth,mRoiHeight);
        Imgproc.rectangle(mRgba,rect1,rect2,new Scalar(0, 255, 0, 255),5);

        roi_rect = new Rect(mRoiX+4,mRoiY+4,mRoiWidth-8,mRoiHeight-8);
        m_matRoi = mRgba.submat(roi_rect);
        Mat temp = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(m_matRoi, temp, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY,0);
        Mat temp_rgba = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(temp, temp_rgba, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA,0);
        temp_rgba.copyTo(m_matRoi);


        scalarLow=new Scalar(0,0,200);
        scalarHigh=new Scalar(180,255,255);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba,mat1,Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);

        Core.inRange(mat1,scalarLow,scalarHigh,mat2);
        Core.bitwise_and(mRgba,mRgba,mat1,mat2);
        mRgba=mat1;


       
        Imgproc.dilate(mRgba,mRgba,new Mat(),new Point(1,2),2);//




        Mat edges=new Mat();
        Imgproc.Canny(mRgba,edges,90,150);

        Mat lines=new Mat();

        Point p1=new Point();
        Point p2=new Point();
        double a,b;
        double x0,y0;
        Imgproc.HoughLinesP(edges,lines,1.0,Math.PI/180.0,50,100.0,10.0);//

        for(int i=0;i<lines.rows();i++) {
            double[] l = lines.get(i, 0);

            Imgproc.line(mRgba, new Point(l[0], l[1]), new Point(l[2], l[3]), new Scalar(0, 0, 255.0), 3);
            
        }


        return mRgba;
    }

}
```

I divided it to two parts b/c there were not necessary codes between them.
Thank you.

Edit1)
To @Jeru Luke, I changed the code you said. I put many slashes where I changed the code.

```
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width ,int height){
        mRgba=new Mat(height,width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
        mGray =new Mat(height,width,CvType.CV_8UC1);

        mat1 = new Mat(height,width,CvType.CV_8UC4);
        mat2 = new Mat(height,width,CvType.CV_8UC4);//////////
        
    }
    public void onCameraViewStopped(){
        mRgba.release();
    }
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame){
        mRgba=inputFrame.rgba();/////mRgba = image, matInput 과 같은 역할
        mGray=inputFrame.gray();


        double m_dWscale = (double)  1/3;
        double m_dHscale = (double) 1/4;
        int mRoiWidth = (int)(mRgba.size().width * m_dWscale);
        int mRoiHeight = (int)(mRgba.size().height * m_dHscale);

        int mRoiX = (int) (mRgba.size().width - mRoiWidth) ;
        int mRoiY = (int) (mRgba.size().height - mRoiHeight) ;

        //rect = new Rect(mRoiX,mRoiY,mRoiWidth,mRoiHeight);
        rect1 =new Point(mRoiX, mRoiY);
        rect2 = new Point(mRoiWidth,mRoiHeight);
        Imgproc.rectangle(mRgba,rect1,rect2,new Scalar(0, 255, 0, 255),5);

        roi_rect = new Rect(mRoiX+4,mRoiY+4,mRoiWidth-8,mRoiHeight-8);
        m_matRoi = mRgba.submat(roi_rect);
        Mat temp = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(m_matRoi, temp, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY,0);
        Mat temp_rgba = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(temp, temp_rgba, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA,0);
        temp_rgba.copyTo(m_matRoi);

        scalarLow=new Scalar(0,0,200);
        scalarHigh=new Scalar(180,255,255);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba,mat1,Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);

        Core.inRange(mat1,scalarLow,scalarHigh,mat2);
        Core.bitwise_and(mRgba,mRgba,mat1,mat2);
        mRgba=mat2;////////////////////////////////////



        
        Imgproc.dilate(mat1,mRgba,new Mat(),new Point(1,2),2);/////////////




        Mat edges=new Mat();
        Imgproc.Canny(mat1,edges,90,150);//////////////////////////

        Mat lines=new Mat();

        Point p1=new Point();
        Point p2=new Point();
        double a,b;
        double x0,y0;
        Imgproc.HoughLinesP(edges,lines,1.0,Math.PI/180.0,50,100.0,10.0);

        for(int i=0;i<lines.rows();i++) {
            double[] l = lines.get(i, 0);

            Imgproc.line(mRgba, new Point(l[0], l[1]), new Point(l[2], l[3]), new Scalar(0, 0, 255.0), 3);
           Scalar(255.0,255.0,255.0),1,Imgproc.LINE_AA,0);

        }


        return mRgba;
    }

}
```

Edit2) My final objective of this project is draw lines only in ROI(Region of Interest) area. Below code is about ROI. But the problem is it only shows rectangular box and lines are everywhere in my phone screen.

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame){
        mRgba=inputFrame.rgba();
        mGray=inputFrame.gray();
        mat3=inputFrame.rgba();


        double m_dWscale = (double)  1/3;
        double m_dHscale = (double) 1/4;
        int mRoiWidth = (int)(mRgba.size().width * m_dWscale);
        int mRoiHeight = (int)(mRgba.size().height * m_dHscale);

        int mRoiX = (int) (mRgba.size().width - mRoiWidth) ;
        int mRoiY = (int) (mRgba.size().height - mRoiHeight) ;

        //rect = new Rect(mRoiX,mRoiY,mRoiWidth,mRoiHeight);
        rect1 =new Point(mRoiX, mRoiY);
        rect2 = new Point(mRoiWidth,mRoiHeight);
        Imgproc.rectangle(mRgba,rect1,rect2,new Scalar(0, 255, 0, 255),5);

        roi_rect = new Rect(mRoiX+4,mRoiY+4,mRoiWidth-8,mRoiHeight-8);
        m_matRoi = mRgba.submat(roi_rect);
        //Mat temp = new Mat();
        //Imgproc.cvtColor(m_matRoi, temp, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY,0);
        //Mat temp_rgba = new Mat();
        //Imgproc.cvtColor(temp, temp_rgba, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA,0);
        //temp_rgba.copyTo(m_matRoi);
```

this part is about ROI.

Edit3) below code is about making mask I guess..

```
roi_rect = new Rect(mRoiX,mRoiY,mRoiWidth,mRoiHeight);
        mat5 = mRgba.submat(roi_rect); 
        //Mat temp = new Mat();
        //Mat temp_rgba = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba,mRgba,Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY); 
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mat5, mat5, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGR,0); //
        //Imgproc.cvtColor(temp, temp_rgba, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA,0);
        mat5.copyTo(mRgba);
```

`roi_rect` 's parameters are all `(int)` and mat5 is

```
mat5 = new Mat(height,width,CvType.CV_8UC4);
```

I made this code firstly to make all region dark. And using `roi_rect` only that part, which means `mat5` is converted `GRAY2BGR` and then use `mat5.copyTo(mRgba)` to paste `mat5` on `mRgba`. But it shuts down when I turn on the app.

Comment: You have detected your lines, you can just draw them on the original BGR image. I don't understand the need for conversion from HSV to BGR

Comment: Very good idea!! Can I know the code how to do that after HoughLinesP()?
I have no idea how to draw them on the original BGR image.
Thank you for reply!

Comment: Before that, what does `Imgproc.line(mRgba, new Point(l[0], l[1]), new Point(l[2], l[3]), new Scalar(0, 0, 255.0), 3);` return? Does it draw the lines onto `mRgba`?

Comment: Yes it does. On my phone, using that code, it displays HSV with lines.

Comment: In your code, you have assigned HSV output to the RGB variable, thus overriding the original RGB input. It happens in line `mRgba=mat1;`. That's why the detected lines are being drawn in HSV color space. Assign a different variable on the same line and try again.

Comment: Do you mean do I have to change ```mRgba = mat2;``` or something?

Comment: Yes. Change `mRgba = mat2;`. Then for `Imgproc.dilate` and `Imgproc.Canny` functions, pass `mat1` as input. The rest would be the same

Comment: I added the changed code in my question. Can you see and tell me which part I lost?
Because when I turn on the App, It still shows the HSV image.

Comment: TBH, I do not code in Java but Python. I have been offering suggestions based on your code. I would suggest creating a copy of the RGB image/frame, perform your operations and finally draw lines on this copy

Comment: Very thank you for your suggestions and spending time to me. Based on your replies I finally got a BGR img with line detections. The problem was in ```Imgproc.dilate(mat1,mRgba,new Mat(),new Point(1,2),2);``` 

When I changed it to ```Imgproc.dilate(mat1,mat1,new Mat(),new Point(1,2),2);```, it finally shows BGR image.

Once again, I want to say very thank you. If you have more time, can I ask 1 more question?

Comment: sure @ywseo97. Will do once I have time

Comment: Thank you! I edited my question. Please see ```Edit2)```.

Comment: Create a mask such that your ROI is in color while other part is black. Draw detected lines on this mask

Comment: Please see Edit3). I made some changes.

Comment: How to make screen black?? I tried making BGR2GRAY, but it still shows lines.

Comment: As I said, I don't know how its done using Java. Hope I have given you an idea how to proceed